# Import a FBX map with latitude and Longitude

Tags: unity-game-engine, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap, fbx

It's possible to import a osm file into cityengine and then export as fbx file with latitude and longitude data of each block? Because then I want to import the fbx file into unity3D and use this information (lat and long) in order to find the current address ...

Do you know how to do it? Or do you have any other idea how to solve it?